# Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager for AspNet Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, unity-container

The Unity DI Container has an extension for ASP.NET MVC (based on the older .NET Framework) that includes PerRequestLifetimeManager.  This allows you to have one instance of an object that has the lifetime of one http request.

I am building an ASPNET Core MVC project and would like to use Unity, but there does not seem to be an equivalent to the PerRequestLifetimeManager in the Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection extension.  Is anyone aware if such a thing exists?